# Ionic CLI not working - Ionic CLI Version: 2.0.0-beta.32

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I try to make a new ionic project. when i run this command line

```
ionic start myProject sidemenu --v2 --ts
```

it is not working anymore, nothing happens.

This is my environtment setup.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It still does not work if you remove the `--ts` and leave just `ionic start bawana sidemenu --v2`?

Comment: No, not work. i have remote the --ts. i try to downgrade the cordova version to 4.2.0, but still not work.

Comment: Have you tried to use the blank template ??

Comment: @MArgusChopinGyver yes i have, still not work.

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of problem do you face, but I think you might try to update the ionic beta first

Comment: Actually, I've update my ionic CLI to your version, and it works well.. Maybe you just need to perform npm install -g ionic@beta again (sometimes, it happen because the ionic lib is at not good condition and need to reinstall)

Comment: I have did, i re install the ionic CLI, and i run the command. but still not work. what is you operating system?